# No se envía el formulario con sweetalert

Tags: php, formularios, validación, sweetalert, sweetalert2

Muy buenas tardes con todos, espero esten bien, estoy creando un formulario y quisiera validar el envío del mismo con sweetalert.

Primero quisiera saber si el formulario se envía una vez se haga clic en enviar, pero no lo hace, adjunto el código acá para ver en que estoy fallando.

He probado ya de varias formas y visto varias soluciones pero también me salen más que nada es que el formulario se envía sin esperar la confirmación del sweetalert, incluyo esta información para dar el mayor contexto posible y que no se etiquete la pregunta como poco informativa o algo así.

**Formulario:**

```
  <form class="text-white needs-validation " action="<?php echo base_url('/evolution_country_data') ?>" name="evolution_country_data" method="post" onsubmit="return executeExample()" class="needs-validation" novalidate>

            <div class="form-row ">
                <div class="col-md-5 mb-0">
                    <label class="" for="indi1">Indicador 1:<br><br>Property rights)</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="indi1" required>

                    <div class="valid-feedback">
                        Looks good!
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-5 mb-0">
                    <label class="" for="indi2">Indicador 2:<br><br>Business impact of rules on FDI</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="indi2" required>

                    <div class="valid-feedback">
                        Looks good!
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="col-md-5 mb-0">
                    <label class="" for="indi3">Indicador 3:<br><br>Government prioritization of travel and tourism industry</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="indi3" required>

                    <div class="valid-feedback">
                        Looks good!
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-5 mb-0">
                    <label class="" for="indi4">Indicador 4:<br><br>T&T government expenditure</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="indi4" required>

                    <div class="valid-feedback">
                        Looks good!
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="col-md-5 mb-0">
                    <label class="" for="indi5">Indicador 5:<br><br>Available seat kilometres, domestic</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="indi5" required>

                    <div class="valid-feedback">
                        Looks good!
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-5 mb-0">
                    <label class="" for="indi6">Indicador 6:<br><br>Available seat kilometres, international</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="indi6" required>

                    <div class="valid-feedback">
                        Looks good!
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <br><br>


            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
                    <div class="col-md-4"> <button type="submit" align="center" class="st_p_cert_evl p-3 text-white" onclick="executeExample('warningConfirm')" value="Enviar">Enviar Datos</button></div>
                    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
                </div>


        </form>
```

**Script de sweetalert:**

```
function executeExample(example) {
    event.preventDefault();
    swal({
            title: "¿Estás seguro de que son los datos correctos?",
            text: "Una vez enviado no podrás modificar tus datos",
            icon: "warning",
            buttons: true,
            dangerMode: true,
        })
        .then((willDelete) => {
            if (willDelete) {
                preConfirm: () => {
                    if (document.getElementsByTagName('input').value) {
                        document.evolution_country_data.submit();

                        /*return [ //alert('faltan datos')
                            document.getElementById('swal-input1').value,
                            document.getElementById('swal-input2').value
                        ]*/
                    } else {
                        alert('faltan datos')
                        swal('<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"> This is a primary alert—check it out!</div>')
                        console.log(aler('faltan datos'))
                    }
                }


            }
            else {

                swal("Envio de datos cancelado!");
            }
        });
}
```

Agradecería mucho su iluminación en cuanto a este tema.

Comment: Debesd quitar el `type="submit"` del boton y cambiarlo por `type="button"` porque sino estas mandando dos acciones a la vez, la del onclick y la del submit.  Si quitas la del submit entonces podras continuar depurando tu código mejor pues entraras en el swal correctamente

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración masterguru, cambie el input por ´type="button"´ y sigue sin enviarse al hacer clic en aceptar o en este casi "ok". No se si es que tengo exceso de código porque en la etiqueta form también tengo la ejecución del script y no estoy seguro de si es así ahora con tantas cosas que ya he probado.